# Java Servlet understanding

Tags: java, servlets, ascii

So I have been asked to create a servlet that reads an ascii file and sends the output to the browser that invokes the servlet.

I have started on this but ultimatly I don't know what exactly the above means...

Here is what I have, could someone tell me if what I have does what is requested? If not what do I need to do to finish my servlet?

```
public class MessageServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    // output an HTML page
    res.setContentType("text/html");

    // load a configuration parameter (you must set this yourself)
    String root = getInitParameter("root");

    // print some html
    ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head><title>Bryan Rigsbee's Page</title></head>");
    out.println("<body><h1>My Test Servlet for Understanding</h1>");

    // print the file
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream
            (new FileInputStream(root + "/message.txt") );
        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) !=-1) {
            out.print((char)ch);
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) in.close();  // very important
    }

    // finish up
    out.println("</body></html>");
}
}
```

Comment: Strange question. If your servlet is doing what you was asked (and you better know if it does) so what is the problem here? Nobody know your requirements better than you.

Comment: If you don't understand the problem you were asked to solve, you need to go back to the person who gave you that problem and ask for clarification.

Comment: I think its good.. You facing any problem please ask the question

Comment: Where does the ascii file come from?

Comment: IMO, this is better suited for - http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It looks like you have done well on putting the ASCII file into the response. Can you post the code you are using in all of your classes on a GitHub Gist or on pastebin.com? I'll check it out on my computer if you do.